# How to track file creation and modification

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We have put together a perl script that essentially looks at the argument that is being passed to it checks if is creating or modifying a file then it saves that in a mysql database so that it is easily accessible later. Here is the interesting part, how do I make this perl script run before all of the commands typed in the terminal. I need to make this dummy proof so people don't forget to run it.

Sorry I didn't formulate this question properly. What I want to do is prepend to each command such that each command will run like so "./run.pl ls" for example. That way I can track file changes if the command is mv or it creates an out file for example. The script pretty much takes care of that but I just don't know how to run it seamlessly to the user.

I am running ubuntu server with the bash terminal.

Thanks

Comment: This is not clear.  When do you want this script to run: When the user first logs on?  When they first open a terminal?  Before every single command that is entered?  Only before specific commands?

Comment: "*essentially looks at the argument that is being passed to it checks if is creating or modifying a file then it saves that in a mysql database*" - *What* is the argument passed to it? *Who* is creating or modifying a file? *What* is saved to the database?

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly you need to execute a function before running every command, something similar to `preexec` and `precmd` in `zsh`.

Unfortunately `bash` doesn't have a native support for this but you can do it using `DEBUG` trap.

[Here](http://hints.macworld.com/dlfiles/preexec.bash.txt) is a sample code applying this method.

[This page](http://blog.pointsoftware.ch/index.php/howto-bash-audit-command-logger/) also provide some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `~/.bashrc` file and launch your script there. Do note that each user would (and should) still have the privelege to modify this file, potentially removing the script invocation.

The `/etc/bash.bashrc` file is system-wide and only changeable by root.

These `.bashrc`s are executed when a new instance of bash is created (e.g. new terminal).

It is not the same as `sh`, the system shell, that is `dash` on Ubuntu systems.